# Interfacing the GPS module with MSP430

Tags: c, embedded

I already interfacing the GPS s-1216 module with 8051. Now I'm going to interfacing the same module with MSP430fr5969 launchpad. I facing the problem in starting itself that to which pin is connection will be doing? can anyone will solve this.. If it possible explain using code functions..

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of this. Either 0 or 1.

```
PIN 20-TX1, PIN 21-RX1; PIN 24-TX0, PIN 25-RX0.
```

Select the appropriate function using selection register as each pin has more than 2 functions. In 8051 there is nothing called selection register. But here it is used to define the function of PIN.
Rest of the things are same as in 8051, like UART configuration, baud rate and TX RX functions.
Before trying UART, try blinky IO program to get the basic knowledge on MSP430